# No sound on my hp monitor via hdmi after updating from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: sound, kernel, hdmi, 22.10

It seems to be in the new Linux kernel as when I reverted back to an older kernel my sound works again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: No sound after updating to 22.10  I am using hdmi hp monitor  The old kernel still works

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

Just add the following to the alsa-base.conf (/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf) and reboot:

options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0

after the reboot I finally had audio again!   It worked for me.